# Changing Shadows in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, window

How to get deep shadow effects in Windows 7? I am a die hard fan of windows and loved every version of windows but I hated shadows effects in every version of Windows. for the record I hate Mac OS :)

Is there any registry value that I can change to achieve the desired shadows?

Regards

Comment: What do you mean? Shadows under windows, menus, tooltips, mouse pointer?

Comment: yes shadows under windows etc